# How can I format a formulaic result in C# Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel-formula, number-formatting, excel-interop

I've got this code that sums the values in the given range (Column O Row 10 to Column O the last signficant row):

**Note:** That's the letter "O" not the number "Zero".

```
var totalTotalPackageCountCell = 
              (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, TOTAL_PACKAGE_COUNT_COLUMN];

totalTotalPackageCountCell.Formula = string.Format("=SUM(O10:O{0})", curDelPerfRow);
```

It works pretty dandy except for one thing: the value displays without commas, such as "20192" (I want it to be "20,192").

I tried this:

```
totalTotalPackageCountCell.Formula = 
              string.Format("=SUM(O10:O{0})", curDelPerfRow)
              .ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

...as `.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` is how I successfully add commas to other values.

In this (formula value) case, though, it doesn't even compile - I get:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments

How can I have my formula and format it, too?

Comment: Try casting to an  integer, then use ToString on it, you have more options that way.

Comment: Just from reading it: You're setting this value to the *formula*. You're trying to format the *formula* expression, not the result. I would imagine the excel library would have a property like 'Format' or something, and you'd have to use an excel-specific expression

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to format this string: `=SUM(O10:O20)`, rather than the *result* (which excel will calculate, not in your application). So, even if it did compile, it wouldn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one. Try to specify the NumberFormat of the cell, before assigning a value.

```
totalTotalPackageCountCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0";
totalTotalPackageCountCell.Formula = string.Format("=SUM(O10:O{0})", curDelPerfRow);
```