# How can I restrict the decimal count in an Excel cell with an "Average" formula?

Tags: c#, excel, decimal, excel-interop, decimal-point

I'm using C# Excel Interop to create spreadsheets. I'm using formulas for a "totals" section at the bottom of a sheet. Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
var totalTotalOrdersCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, TOTAL_ORDERS_COLUMN];
totalTotalOrdersCell.Formula = string.Format("=SUM(J10:J{0})", curDelPerfRow);

var avgAvgWeeklyDeliveriesCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, AVG_WEEKLY_DELIVERIES_COLUMN];
avgAvgWeeklyDeliveriesCell.Formula = string.Format("=AVERAGE(K10:K{0})", curDelPerfRow);

var avgAvgOrderAmountCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, AVG_ORDER_AMOUNT_COLUMN];
avgAvgOrderAmountCell.Formula = string.Format("=AVERAGE(L10:L{0})", curDelPerfRow);

var avgAvgPackageCountCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, AVG_PACKAGE_AMOUNT_COLUMN];
avgAvgPackageCountCell.Formula = string.Format("=AVERAGE(M10:M{0})", curDelPerfRow);

var totalTotalSalesCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, TOTAL_SALES_COLUMN];
totalTotalSalesCell.Formula = string.Format("=SUM(N10:N{0})", curDelPerfRow);

var totalTotalPackageCountCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, TOTAL_PACKAGE_COUNT_COLUMN];
totalTotalPackageCountCell.Formula = string.Format("=SUM(O10:O{0})", curDelPerfRow);
```

This is what is being produced:

[image]

The monetary/currency vals are formatting just right, without any intervention from me - Excel is apparently smart about money.

As to the integers, though, not so much - it shows "20192" instead of "20,192" - but I already asked about that particular issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032569/how-can-i-format-a-formulaic-result-in-c-sharp-excel-interop).

My question now is - and it's a "bigger deal" - how can I restrict the decimal count on the averaged values? I want "15.23" not "15.23076923" and "34.17" not the much longer and more precise version of the value.

How can I tell the Formula former that two decimal points is enough?

Comment: As I commented in the other post, it's almost definitely in a property/setting on the cell which you pass in an *excel format*, which would also include decimal places. For example: `#,##0.00` (in excel itself, I'd assume the library uses the same notation) will format `1000` to `1,000.00` and `2.31231` to `2.31`

Comment: I would try it the Excel way.. `=ROUND(AVERAGE(M10:M{0}), 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `=TEXT` formula? - syntax is like this: `=TEXT("412.24134","#,###.00")` and the answer will be displayed as `412.24`:

so wrt your code, something like this (has not been tested):

```
var avgAvgWeeklyDeliveriesCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curDelPerfRow + 2, AVG_WEEKLY_DELIVERIES_COLUMN];
avgAvgWeeklyDeliveriesCell.Formula = string.Format("=TEXT(AVERAGE(K10:K{0})", curDelPerfRow),"#,###.00");
```